# Delete duplicate entries from a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I, using jQuery, remove the dups

```
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Geology">Geology</option>
        <option value="Geology">Geology</option>
        <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="Music">Music</option>
        <option value="Music">Music</option>
        <option value="Zoology">Zoology</option>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
var found = [];
$("select option").each(function() {
  if($.inArray(this.value, found) != -1) $(this).remove();
  found.push(this.value);
});
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/baPQc/), it's a simple approach, we're just keeping an array of found values, if we haven't found the value, add it to the array ([`.push()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)), if we *have* found the value, this one's a dupe we found earlier, [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it.

This only crawls the `<select>` once, minimizing DOM traversal which is a *lot* more expensive than array operations.  Also we're using [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead of `.indexOf()` so this works properly in IE.

---

If you want a less efficient but shorter solution (just for illustration, use the first method!):

```
$('select option').each(function() {
  $(this).prevAll('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/gjmtM/), this removes all siblings with the same value, but it's much more expensive than the first method (DOM Traversal is expensive, and multiple selector engine calls here, many more).  We're using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) because you can't just remove [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) inside an [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), it'll cause some errors with the loop since it expected the next child.
​

Comment: Comment to help the rookies like me. If you use a jQuery noconflict make sure you replace all the $ with whatever you chose. Will save you a lot of time debugging. :) - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @JoshuaDance you can also wrap all of this in a function where `$` is jQuery inside to simplify things, like this: `(function($) { ...code... })(jQuery);` (or something else if it's not `jQuery`). This means that whatever you chose goes 1 place, rather than having to modify every bit of code or plugin you want to use.

Comment: This method will stop duplicates in **ALL** selects on the page. For example If you had multiple yes/no selects only the first one will have options.  Duplicate the select in your fiddle and test. So no option will appear on the page more than once. hth

Comment: @JoeJohnston You can write `$('select#selectID option')` instead of just `$('select option')` to resolve this problem.

Comment: on more issue it's not displaying any options on click

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way that came into my mind was using siblings

```
$("select>option").each( function(){

 var $option = $(this);  

 $option.siblings()
       .filter( function(){ return $(this).val() == $option.val() } )
       .remove()


})
```

Answer (score 1):

From top of my head, untested:

```
$('#mySelect option').each(function(){
  if ($('#mySelect option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').length) $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use below code to remove duplicate options:

```js
$("#color option").val(function(idx, val) {
  $(this).siblings("[value='"+ val +"']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class ="select-form" name="color" id="color">
  <option value="">Select Color</option>
  <option value="1">Color 1</option>
  <option value="2">Color 2</option>
  <option value="3">Color 3</option>
  <option value="3">Color 3</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="2">Color 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
</select>
```

Comment: not working if select have already some options it reset all values to null and then in next case it remove all.