# How to remove duplicates between two Html select lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two HTML select list and i want to remove all the elements in list 1 which are similar to elements in list 2.

```
<select id="availableLanguages" name="availableSoftwareLanguages" multiple="multiple" size="15">
    <option value="AL" label="All Languages">All Languages</option>
    <option value="AG" label="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="BU" label="Bulgarian">Bulgarian</option>
    <option value="CF" label="Canadian French">CanadianFrench</option>
    <option value="C1" label="Cantonese">Cantonese</option>
</select>

<input id="addLanguages" type="button" value=" >> ">
<input id="removeLanguages" type="button" value=" << ">

<select id="selectedLanguages" name="selectedLanguages " multiple="multiple" size="15">
    <option value="AL" label="All Languages">All Languages</option>
    <option value="AG" label="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="BU" label="Bulgarian">Bulgarian</option>
</select>
```

So here i want to remove options from list availableLanguages which are similar to options in list selectedLanguages.

Comment: *"So here i want to remove options from list availableLanguages which are similar to options in list selectedLanguages."* Define "similar." And separately: What have **you** tried? Where have you run into trouble? Or do you just want people to write code for you?

Comment: This question might give you the answer you're searching for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227754/delete-duplicate-entries-from-a-select-box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're matching by option value? If so, try:

```
$("#selectedLanguages option").each(function () {
    $("#availableLanguages option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
});
```

Comment: can u implement this function without jquery?